# Reference request: maximal determinant of matrices with pairwise orthogonal rows and entries in $\{1, 0, -1\}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, random-matrices, matrix-theory, combinatorial-optimization, orthogonal-matrices

We know that "Hadamard maximal determinant problem" concerns the largest determinant of a matrix of oder $n$ with entries in $\{-1,1\}$ or $\{0, 1\}$. For $n=4k$, it is the Hadamard conjecture; and for the other orders, many important bounds (both upper and lower) have been obtained by Barba, Ehlich, and Wojtas and others. I would like know if there has been work towards providing bound for the largest determinant of the matrices of order $n \neq 4k$ with pairwise orthogonal rows and entries in $\{0, 1, -1\}$?

Comment: I don't know what the orthogonality condition does to the answer, but without that condition the maximum determinant for $\{-1,0,1\}$ is the same as for $\{-1,1\}$.

Comment: @Brendan It surely makes a difference, the maximal matrices for {-1, 1} that have been worked out (that I know of) in the literatures for order not equal to 4k, do not satisfy the orthogonality condition.

Comment: Just to get the ball rolling, if $f(n)$ is the answer and $m$ is the largest number $\leq n$ for which there exists a Hadamard matrix of order $m$, then $f(n)\geq m^{m/2}f(n-m)$.

Comment: Maximum determinants for $n=1,2,\dots,8$ are: $$1,2,2,16,16,125,128,4096$$

Comment: @RichardStanley: More generally, $f(n)\geq f(m)f(n-m)$ for any $m\in[1,n-1]$.

Comment: If $n \equiv 2 \bmod 4$ there do not exist three orthogonal $\pm 1$ vectors. So you could have at most two $n$'s in the Gram matrix, and if you have at least one a parity argument shows the determinant would be at most the square root of $n^2(n-2)^{n-2}$. You can do better with a conference matrix, which is a matrix with zero's on the diagonal, $\pm 1$ elsewhere satisfying $MM^{\top} = (n-1)I_{n}$. So these should be the optimal solutions when $n \equiv 2 \mod 4$, when they exist. The order must be a sum of two squares; the Paley construction with $q \equiv 1 \mod 4$ gives an infinite family.

Comment: If $n$ is odd, there must be an odd number of zero terms in the inner product of any two rows. In particular, for any two rows, there are an odd number of columns where both are zero. If all the zeroes don't lie in a column, the combinatorics becomes interesting (and the problem seems hard). If they're all in a column and there exists a Hadamard matrix of order $n-1$, it seems the direct sum with a $1\times 1$ matrix would be hard to beat, at least at large orders.

Comment: I've added the maximum determinants to the OEIS as https://oeis.org/A352348 At the moment it has terms for $n\leq 10$.