# Orthogonal vectors with entries from $\{-1,0,1\}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathbf{1}$ be the all-ones vector, and suppose $\mathbf{1}, \mathbf{v_1}, \mathbf{v_2}, \ldots, \mathbf{v_{n-1}} \in \{-1,0,1\}^n$ are mutually orthogonal non-zero vectors. Does it follow that $n \in \{1,2\} \cup \{4k : k \in \mathbb{N}\}$?

A few notes are in order:

1. If we do not allow "$0$" entries in the vectors then this is a well-known necessary condition for the existence of an $n \times n$ [Hadamard matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix), so the answer to my question is "yes" if we replace $\{-1,0,1\}$ with$\{-1,1\}$.
2. With some computer help, I have shown that there do not exist collections of vectors with these properties when $n = 3$, $5$, or $6$, so the answer to my question is "yes" when $n \leq 6$.

**Edit (May 19, 2023):** In the comments, Max Alekseyev has shown that the answer is "yes" when $n \leq 12$, and Ilya Bogdanov has shown that the answer is "yes" when $n$ is an odd prime.

Comment: Interesting! Would the answer change if we replace the "orthogonality" requirement with "independence"?

Comment: @Amir: If you just require linear independence then you can always (for all $n$) find such a set of vectors. Furthermore, if you just require linear independence then whenever $n$ is even you can find such a set of vectors with entries in $\{-1,1\}$.

Comment: @NathanielJohnston Which condition prevents all $\mathbf{v_i}$ to be the $0$-vectors?

Comment: @Peter: Thanks, I do need that condition so I'll add that in. (I'm reminded of a time when I asked my linear algebra students to produce some orthogonal vectors satisfying certain conditions, and lots of them got easy marks since I forgot to specify "non-zero"...)

Comment: Somewhat relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/q/418009

Comment: I confirm the affirmative answer for all $n\leq 10$ with ILP.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev ... and so did I using cliquer. Presently running $n=11$ which might take a while ...

Comment: Maybe linear algebra modulo $4$ is relevant, as these vectors miss $2 \bmod 4$? There is also a natural combinatorial interpretation -- with each $\mathbf{v}_i$ associate disjoint subsets $A_i^+$, $A^-_i$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ defined by $A^{\pm}_i=\{j: (\mathbf{v}_{i})_j=\pm 1\}$. Then $|A^+_i|=|A^-_i|$ by orthogonality of $\mathbf{v}_i$ with $\mathbf{1}$. The rest of the orthogonality conditions are encoded by $|A^+_i \cap A^+_j| + |A^-_i \cap A^-_j| = |A^+_i \cap A^-_j| + |A^-_i \cap A^+_j|$ for $i \neq j$.

Comment: @PeterMueller: I've also checked with cliquer and it confirmed no solutions for $n=11$ within a couple of hours. So, the "yes" answer holds for all $n\leq 12$.

Comment: The question seems related to [weighing matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighing_matrix) except that the all-ones vector kind of messes things up.

Comment: Do you have a construction for such a matrix for every $n$ that is divisible by 4, or only for those $n$ for which there exists a Hadamard matrix?

Comment: @domotorp - Only when there's a Hadamard matrix.

Comment: As a first step, $n$ cannot be an odd prime. This is because the matrix $A$ composed from those columns should be such that $D=A^TA$ is diagonal, so $B=AD^{-1/2}$ should be orthogonal. But the diagonal element s in $BB^T$ may equal $1$ only I’d $D=nI$ which is impossible by Hadamard. It seems that one may investigate $BB^T$ or, equivalently, the relation $AD^{-1}A^T=I$  further…

Comment: @Ilya - Can you expand upon the statement "But the diagonal elements in $BB^T$ may equal $1$ only if $D = nI$"? I expect that this is the step that is using the hypothesis of $n$ being an odd prime, but I'm having a hard time seeing how.

Comment: @NathanielJohnston Each diagonal element of $BB^T$ is a sum of $n$ njmbers each of them is either 0 or  of the form $1/k$ with $k\leq n$. At least one summand is $1/n$; if there are less than $n$ such, then $n$ in the denominators cannot cancel.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov - Very nice, thank you! I think your argument can be extended to all odd numbers, not just odd primes. For example, if $n = 15$ then (by your denominators-cancelling argument) there must be at least 3 columns of $A$ that have all $15$ entries with no $0$s (since then you can get $1/15 + 1/15 + 1/15 = 1/5$ to reduce the denominator). But the standard proof of the Hadamard necessary condition says that you can't have $3$ orthogonal columns of $\pm 1$ entries unless $n \in \{1,2\} \cup \{4k\}$.

Comment: Very interesting. If the all 1 vector is removed there are solutions with odd lengths.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov - And a similar argument works to rule out the $n \equiv 2\pmod{4}$ cases, thus proving the entire thing. Suppose $n = 2m$ for some odd number $m$. Then (again, by your denominators-cancelling argument) $A$ must have at least $2$ columns with all entries non-zero (one of which is the all-ones column). If it had $3$ or more such columns we get the Hadamard contradiction, so assume it has exactly $2$. The remaining columns each have their number of non-zero entries each equal to factors of $m$, which are all odd. Such columns cannot be orthogonal to $\mathbf{1}$. Contradiction.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov - If you agree with my reasoning, please feel free to write this up as an answer and I will accept it. Your denominators-cancelling argument is what blew this open. Thank you!

Comment: @NathanielJohnston The life seems more complicated for me. E.g.,  it could happen that the sum involves $1/15$,  $2\times 1/6$ and  $6\times 1/10$ (,the other denominators should be even!). However, this may fasten algorithms searching such matrices.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov - You're quite right, thank you.

Comment: @kodlu Yes, even many such weighing matrixes exist. But the all-1 column changes a lot.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov's argument also seems to apply when $n = p^k$ for $p$ odd prime. For the diagonal element we have $1 = 1/p^k + \ldots$, which has to involve at least $p - 1$ more $1/p^k$'s. But two odd-sized full rows are already a contradiction.

Comment: Further, $n = 2p$ for odd prime $p$ is also a no-go. $1 = 1/2p + \ldots$ requires at least one more $1/2p$, and their sum $1 / p$ requires an extra (even) denominator divisible by $p$ (thus, another $2p$). We now have three full rows, which is enough to invoke Hadamard.

Comment: Of course, $2p^k$ ditto.

Comment: @MikhailTikhomirov: What does "invoke Hadamard" stand for?

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Same argument that establishes that Hadamard matrices are of order $1$, $2$, or $4k$. If there are three mutually orthogonal ±1-vectors $\mathbf{1}$, $v_1$, $v_2$, then the number of indices $i$ where $v_{1i} = s_1$, $v_{2i} = s_2$ is the same for any of the four combinations of $s_1, s_2 \in \{+1, -1\}$.

Comment: I've computationally verified the conjecture $n=15$ and together with Ilya's and Mikhail's arguments that makes it proved for all $n\leq 20$. For $n=21$, I can tell for now that if a counterexample exists, it should have at least 6 vectors with exactly 14 nonzero components.